# Csh script won't exit when it was invoked by a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a Bash script to invoke a Csh script. After the Csh script finishing, it will not exit, even an "exit" command was appended in the last of the file. The following are scripts:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
./test1.csh

$ cat test1.csh
#!/bin/csh
echo "I'am test1.csh"
exit
```

When I run the "test.sh", [the Csh script did not exit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NEfo.png)

Using `ps -ef | grep test`, found that the process is still running, [as shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvLBG.png)

Comment: Your example works for me, though it did take a longish time as a result of `csh` processing my environment's startup files.  I set the two scripts executable, and issued the command `./test.sh`.  The output from `test1.csh` was, eventually, printed, and the script exited.  No `csh` process lingered.

Comment: You can suppress csh's startup-file processing by adding a `-f` option to the shebang line in `test1.csh`.

Comment: add a "set -x" at the beginning of each scripts, to get on stderr the progression, it will help to see the latest cmd or function called before it hangs

Comment: Thanks John. After 8 hours, I relogin the system and found it could works. I just feel suprise about the issue. Before the issue occurred, I executed a command "killall -u $USER". After that, as you known. So, I just wondering it is because of a "killall" issue? Why does it works after several hours?